# Why do I have a million null characters at the end of my CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am generating a CSV export of data on the fly. I do this by getting a hashset of items, then transforming them row for row and writing them to a MemoryStream, which in turn gets sent to the client as a FileResult. Problem is there is about a million NULL characters at the end of the file, I would guess the number of these characters is equal to the number of items in the hashset. But they're at the end of the file, not the end of each line.

Anyways, the code is like such:

The Controller method:

```
public ActionResult ExportList(ListExportModel model)
{
  System.IO.MemoryStream ms = ls.ExportListToCsv(model,Server.MapPath("~/uploads"));
  return File(ms.GetBuffer(),"text/csv",model.MailingList.ListName + ".csv");
}
```

The ExportListToCsv method

```
public MemoryStream ExportListToCsv(ListExportModel model, string folderpath)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", model.Columns));
    var data = GetListItemsFromCsv(model.ListId, folderpath);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    // Parallel.ForEach(data, (li) =>
    foreach (var li in data)
    {
        string line = "";
        foreach (var field in model.Columns)
        {
            doc.LoadXml(li.CustomFields);
            switch (field)
            {
                //our standard fields
                    case "email":
                        line += li.Email + ",";
                        break;
                    case "tel":
                        line += li.Tel + ",";
                        break;

                    default:
                        line += (doc.SelectNodes("//" + field))[0].Value + ",";
                        break;
                }
            }

            writer.WriteLine(line.TrimEnd(','));
        }
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

And the file (all dummy data, no actual persons were harmed during the making of the screenshot):
[image]

Note: I get the same results regardless of whether I use

> writer.Flush()

and

> stream.Position = 0

or not

Comment: GetBuffer documentation Remark section: `Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the ToArray method; however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in memory.`

Comment: I was hoping to get around having to copy a 60MB filestream, but if I can't, I can't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are calling `GetBuffer()` instead of `ToArray()`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray

> This method omits **unused bytes** in MemoryStream from the array. To get
>   the entire buffer, use the GetBuffer method.
>
> This method returns a copy of the contents of the MemoryStream as a
>   byte array. If the current instance was constructed on a provided byte
>   array, a copy of the section of the array to which this instance has
>   access is returned. See the MemoryStream constructor for details.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Could you explain why this would cause the nulls?

Comment: @JuannStrauss: I added the link to the docs, it has a small explanation.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day! Thanks, that worked.

Comment: I'll add the explanation to your question for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there could be a lot of blank lines at the end of your .csv file. This would cause the default: case to be executed numerous times at the end of processing.

Comment: Not the case. The switch() is executed per line, so if that where the case, I'd see a null at the end of each line, not all together at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, but if you had a lot of blank lines at the end of your input file, that would give you a NULL per empty line, but all gathered together at the end of the file. I see you have an answer though, that's great.